# 'loading' message while tabs() loading ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

Using jQuery UI `tabs()` - with ajax, drawing the content from other pages.

Its working fine, but sometimes the content takes few seconds to load - I would like to have a 'loading...' message in the tab content area.

This is my code currently (used for applying `colorbox()` to relevant links within the ajax content):

```
$("#tabs").tabs().bind('tabsload',function(event, ui){
    $("#tabs .iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"65%", height:"80%"});
});
```

I have seen the suggestions at [JQuery UI Tabs - "Loading..." message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730154/jquery-ui-tabs-loading-message) but none of them seem to work. Maybe they are outdated.

Help appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: The highest rated answer in you linked question depends on .is(':empty'). Perhaps there is an unexpected item in the tab causing that command not to trigger?

Comment: Thanks - i tried commenting out the `.is(":empty")` so that it always inserts the `loading...` but nothing actually happened when tested

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onLoad` callback function..

Sample

```
$("#tabs .iframe").colorbox({
    iframe:true, 
    width:"65%", 
    height:"80%",
    onLoad : function(){
        $("#cboxContent").before('<div class="tab-loading" style="z-indez:999999; position: absolute; background: white; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 35% 45%; ">Loading...</div>'); 
    },
    onComplete : function(){
        $(".tab-loading").remove(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe i wasn't clear - the `colorbox()` call is just for links that appear within the ajax-generated content. It doesn't have anything to do with the loading. i Just need it there so that its applied to the content thats  generated via ajax.