# Loading message inside tab content

Tags: javascript, ajax, c#-4.0

I am using jQuery UI tabs in my page. When one tab is clicked an ajax call goes on and content is prepared and displayed. Ajax call and content preparation takes 5-6 second.

When I click on tab my screen remain idle after 6 second the tab content is shown. But I want to show loading message. How to do it?

Comment: `alert("Please wait")` is an easy way... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate/very close to [JQuery UI Tabs - “Loading…” message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730154/jquery-ui-tabs-loading-message)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has global AJAX handlers that it will call during the processing of an AJAX request.  On the ajaxStart handler you could unhide a progress GIF and on the ajaxComplete handler hide it.

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        // Show GIF
    })
    .ajaxComplete(function() {
        // Hide GIF
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made the ajax call  **Async: true** and placed a loading message as content before ajax call. And its working fine for me..

Thank you all for your responses